# get sum of column if ID is repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tables and I want the sum of the column if the ID is repeated

```
CountValues      ID
____________________
1                23
4                23
2                12
2                23
```

If ID is repeated then CountValues must be sum of ID itself like below

```
CountValues      ID
____________________
7                23
2                12
```

What should be the sql query?

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select sum(CountValues) as CountValues, ID
from TABLE
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` aggregate function together with the `group by` clause:

```
select sum(CountValues) as CountValues, ID
from tbl 
group by ID
```

Comment: For completeness, add ID to the query... ;-) I can't modify the code since the change is less than 6 chars long

Answer (score 0):

Use the aggregate function `SUM` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select SUM(CountValues) as CountValues, ID
from your_table_name
group by ID;
```